# Can't resolve 'fs' in react-script

Tags: node-modules

We tried updating react-scripts from 4.0.3 to 5.0.0 with react-data-export 0.6.0 and xlsx 0.17.2, and when we try to build it fails with the error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in react-data-export\node_modules\tempa-xlsx

What fix needs to be applied to maintain react-scripts version 5.0.0?
I am using react-scripts and not webpack. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this in `node_modules\react-data-export\node_modules\tempa-xlsx\package.json`

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

Worked with me.

Edit:
I just found out that I can't create Excel files anymore. After some research, it seems that 'fs' (which is used to interact with file system) was removed from react-scripts 5. So the only solution is to either use react-scripts 4.0.3, or use another Excel library.

Answer (score 0):

Although adding `"fs":false` is a temporary fix, you might not be able to export excel files altogether. This package is not being maintained [anymore](https://github.com/securedeveloper/react-data-export/issues/168#issuecomment-1075873779). I would suggest go for [react-export-excel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-export-excel)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fs package:

```
yarn add fs
```

and change your code import to the browser version of xlsx-populate.

```
import XlsxPopulate from "xlsx-populate/browser/xlsx-populate";
```

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem too after update "react-scripts" to "^5.0.1"
for resolve this problem add this to `node_modules\tempa-xlsx\package.json` :

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
}
```